# How to write PL/SQL to check if record exists first, before inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

***BACKGROUND:*** I have the tables:

**TUTPRAC:** CLASSID, UNITCODE, STAFFNO, CLASSDAY, CLASSTIME, CLASSTYPE, ROOMNUM

**UNITSTREAM:** STREAMID, UNITCODE, STAFFNO, DAY, TIME, LOCATION

***PROBLEM:*** So i've got a database and tables and im trying to make a function that checks to see if a class is open before opening a new class, the
procedure has to make sure that there isn't any overlaps (clash in terms of time-day or location) between
streams (lectures), tute sessions and prac classes for that particular unit. TUTPRACS contains the records for both tutorials and practicals while UNITSTREAM containts the records for streams (Lectures).

i also want the procedure to also
raise an exception called CLASS_OVERLAPS that prints an alert message in case of a clash.

I'm quite new to PL/SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
           p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
           p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
           p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
           p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
           p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
           p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN

      INSERT INTO TUTPRAC ("CLASSID", "UNITCODE", "CLASS_DAY", "CLASS_TIME", "CLASS_TYPE", "ROOMNUM") 
      VALUES (p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm);

      COMMIT;

    END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
           p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
           p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
           p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
           p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
           p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
           p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN

DECLARE
    x NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
    -- checks
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM TUTPRAC WHERE CLASSID = p_class and UNITCODE  = p_unitc and CLASS_DAY = p_classd and CLASS_TIME = p_classt and CLASS_TYPE = p_classtp and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) , 0) INTO x FROM dual;

    -- insert
    IF (x = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO TUTPRAC ("CLASSID", "UNITCODE", "CLASS_DAY", "CLASS_TIME", "CLASS_TYPE", "ROOMNUM") 
      VALUES (p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm);
    END IF;

END;
```

Or you can use EXISTS like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
               p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
               p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
               p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
               p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
               p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
               p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
        IS
        BEGIN

          INSERT INTO TUTPRAC ("CLASSID", "UNITCODE", "CLASS_DAY", "CLASS_TIME", "CLASS_TYPE", "ROOMNUM") 
INSERT INTO table
SELECT p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm
  FROM dual 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                     FROM TUTPRAC 
                    WHERE CLASSID = p_class and UNITCODE  = p_unitc and CLASS_DAY = p_classd and CLASS_TIME = p_classt and CLASS_TYPE = p_classtp and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm
                  )
```

Comment: I'm just about to give this and the above comment a try, i also wanted to check that the class being inserted isn't clashing with a stream (lecture) in the UNITSTREAM table. Essentially what i'm doing is making sure the TUT or PRAC being entered into the TUTPRAC table does not clash or have any duplicates, and also not clash with its own stream (lecture) day/time/and room. @Rahul Tripathi

Comment: @CM25:- You can try to create one more variable and then check in your table like `SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM UNITSTREAM  WHERE CLASSID = p_class and UNITCODE  = p_unitc and CLASS_DAY = p_classd and CLASS_TIME = p_classt and CLASS_TYPE = p_classtp and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) , 0) INTO x FROM dual;` And then in your IF condition you can use and condtion to check if both the variables have value = 1.

Comment: I I got this error when i entered in the first solution you sent me = "Error(23,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge" Also i am using SQLdeveloper for this. @Rahul Tripathi

Answer (score 1):

Do you know merge? [Merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE open_class(
           p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
           p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
           p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
           p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
           p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
           p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
   merge into TUTPRAC a
   using (select p_class CLASSID,
                 p_unitc UNITCODE,
                 p_classd CLASS_DAY,
                 p_classt CLASS_TIME,
                 p_classtp CLASS_TYPE,
                 p_roomnm ROOMNUM from dual) b
      on (a.CLASSID = b.CLASSID
          and a.UNITCODE = b.UNITCODE
          and a.CLASS_DAY = b.CLASS_DAY
          and a.CLASS_TYPE = b.CLASS_TYPE
          and a.ROOMNUM = b.ROOMNUM)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (a.CLASSID ,a.UNITCODE, a.CLASS_DAY, a.CLASS_TYPE, a.ROOMNUM)
   values  ( b.CLASSID
          , b.UNITCODE
          , b.CLASS_DAY
          , b.CLASS_TYPE
          , b.ROOMNUM);
   if sql%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Class alredy exists');
   else
   dbms_output.put_line('Class added');
   end if;
  commit;
END;
/
```

Comment: Is there a way to also check those same fields in TUTPRAC but from the UNITSTREAMS table? UNITSTREAMS table contains lectures for the same units while TUTPRAC consists of TUTES and PRACS. So i need to make sure tutes and pracs also do not clash with their own lectures which are stored in UNITSTREAM. @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz

Comment: Will this code also detect clashes between 2 different classes in the same room/time/day ? So if there is a Math class in room A at 6.45pm on a wednesday, and we try to add in a Science class in that room at the same time and day, would the above code detect that clash ? @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz

Answer (score 0):

### Keeping It Simple

Here's a simplier way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
       p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
       p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
       p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
       p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
       p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
       p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO TUTPRAC ("CLASSID", "UNITCODE", "CLASS_DAY", "CLASS_TIME", "CLASS_TYPE", "ROOMNUM") 
  SELECT p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM   TUTPRAC 
         WHERE  CLASSID = p_class 
         AND    UNITCODE = p_unitc 
         AND CLASS_DAY = p_classd 
         AND CLASS_TIME = p_classt 
         AND CLASS_TYPE = p_classtp 
         AND ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) = 0;

  COMMIT;

END;
```